# How do I access the contents of my flash drive while booting from it? [Xubuntu]

Tags: mount, filesystem, xubuntu, usb-drive, yumi

I'm trying to recover some files from a Windows computer using a Xubuntu live bootable flash drive. I've found the files that I want to copy on my Windows drive, but don't know how to mount the flash drive that I'm running the USB image from to copy the files over. It doesn't show up in Thunar, just my Windows drive and the virtual Xubuntu filesystem. What I need is the physical flash drive filesystem, the one that contains the ISO that I'm booting from.

Is there a command that I can run to mount the drive?

Here is the output of `lsusb`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/dev$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:3307 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2412 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0424:2412 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c063 Logitech, Inc.
```

I think that bus 001 device 003 is my flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using **Wubi**:
  As i recall, `/host` is the mount point for the Windows Drive that ubuntu is installed on using Wubi.
- When booting **from Flash Drive**:
  After searching with GParted, I found that the drive is mounted under `/cdrom`, not /host

Comment: `bash: cd: /host: No such file or directory` - Doesn't look like it is mounted, unfortunately.

Comment: As for my /dev directory, I have sda, sda1, sda2, sdb, and sdb1. Do any of these sound like flash drives? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, found it! After searching GParted I found that the drive is mounted under `/cdrom`, not `/host`. Solved.